# i run into an error registering azure ml sdk output data into the datastore

Tags: azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk

[image]

I am doing data engineering on my data for ML but after editing and adding some columns i cant register the output to the datastore  and i get the error on the image
how can I solve this error?

Answer (score -1):

i checked my data type and found that was the problem
df.info()
and make sure the formats are ok